# How to add content type field for every part of multipart form data in golang?

Tags: go, file-upload, multipartform-data, content-type

Need to add Content-Type for a file upload seperately, currently it is going as `application/octet-stream` but need to send `application/json` instead.

slice of the code, but don't know if its required.

```
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(paramName, filepath.Base(path))
```

need to change the content type for file that's being uploaded.

Comment: What's wrong with just setting the content type? E.g. like part.Header.Set("Content-Type", "whatever") ?

Comment: @Volker need to validate the content-type of file separately and form should be a multipart form data.

Comment: I have to admit I have no idea what you are asking, what the problem is or how I could help any further.

Comment: @Volker don't worry, i have solved it. thanks! though. may be i'll post the answer later.